# Contract Inheritence

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20, inheritance, openzeppelin-contracts

Let's suppose we created two contracts: Contract A and Contract B.

Contract A is inherit by Zeppelin's standard token ERC20 where as 
Contract B is inherit by contract A.

Will contract B be considered as another ERC20 token?

Comment: I am not sure I follow your description. You mean that A inherits B like `A is B` and also B inherits A like `B is A`?

Comment: @Dominik I mean, **A is StandardToken**. This makes A contract an ERC20 standard token which is the main contract that will be deployed. There's another contract B which is inherited by A i.e. **B is A**. Will this inheritance makes contract B an ERC20 token too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not be a new ERC20 token. When inheriting contracts as you described, only one token will be created no matter how many times you inherit the contracts, as there is only one instance of Zeppelin's StandardToken ERC20.